# Writing an iOS http Post class

Tags: ios, http, http-post

I'm trying to write a class that I can use to make HTTP Post requests and retrieve the results of the request. Something isn't quite connected because I'm getting no confirmations whatsoever, even failure messages. My first two NSLogs get generated but nothing ever comes back from the connection methods. Nothing crashes, it just doesn't return. Here is the only output that I get:

```
&first=vic&second=tory
www.mySite.com/phpTest.php
```

I'm able to successfully make simple HTTP requests, so I know that my problem isn't related to connectivity and such. Also, for the moment, this php script disregards the parameters that I am sending to it so that I can keep this as simple as possible for testing/debugging. All that should happen is that the word "success" should be returned.

Can anyone see what is going wrong? Thank you!

Here is my calling method:

```
- (IBAction)phpTest:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    //set post string with actual parameters
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&first=%@&second=%@", @"vic", @"tory"];
    NSString *script = @"phpTest.php";

    NSLog(@"%@", post);

    MyDownloader *d = [[MyDownloader alloc] initWithPost:post script:script];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(finished:)
                                                 name:@"connectionFinished"
                                               object:d];

    [d.connection start];

}

- (void) finished: (NSNotification *) n
{
    MyDownloader *d = [n object];
    NSData *data = nil;
    if ([n userInfo]) {
        NSLog(@"information retrieval failed");
    } else {
        data = d.receivedData;
        NSString *text=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:d.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", text);

    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name: @"connectionFinished"
                                                  object:d];

}
```

MyDownloader.m

```
@interface MyDownloader()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSMutableURLRequest *request;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *postString;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *script;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableData *mutableReceivedData;
@end

@implementation MyDownloader

- (NSData *) receivedData
{
    return [self.mutableReceivedData copy];
}

- (id) initWithPost: (NSString *)post
            script : (NSString *)script
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self->_postString = post;
        self->_script = script;
        self->_connection =
            [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
        self->_mutableReceivedData = [NSMutableData new];
    }

    //Encode the post string using NSASCIIStringEncoding and also the post string you need to send in NSData format.
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    //You need to send the actual length of your data. Calculate the length of the post string.
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    //Create a Urlrequest with all the properties like HTTP method, http header field with length of the post string.
    //Create URLRequest object and initialize it.
    self.request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    // make a string with the url
    NSString *url = [@"www.mySite.com/" stringByAppendingString:script];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);

    // Set the Url for which your going to send the data to that request.
    [self.request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    //Now, set HTTP method (POST or GET).
    [self.request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //Set HTTP header field with length of the post data.
    [self.request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    //Also set the Encoded value for HTTP header Field.
    [self.request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

    // Set the HTTPBody of the urlrequest with postData.
    [self.request setHTTPBody:postData];

    return self;
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.mutableReceivedData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveRespongs");
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
     [self.mutableReceivedData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        postNotificationName:@"connectionFinished"
        object:self userInfo:@{@"error":error}];

    NSLog(@"-connection:didFailWithError: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        postNotificationName:@"connectionFinished" object:self];
    NSLog(@"didFinishLoading");
}

- (void) cancel
{
    // cancel download in progress, replace connection, start over
    [self.connection cancel];
    self->_connection =
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self->_request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
}

@end
```

Comment: print_r your $_POST array at php end and share what you are getting

Comment: just click on the link that I gave and you will see it in your browser. As I mentioned in my post, I'm getting nothing at all in my simulator.

Comment: ya but i want to know that is php getting the data witch you are trying to send from objective c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. The way you have configured the URL for the `NSURLRequest` is invalid. This line is missing the URL scheme:

   ```
   NSString *url = [@"www.example.com/" stringByAppendingString:script];
   ```

   and should be:

   ```
   NSString *url = [@"http://www.example.com/" stringByAppendingString:script];
   ```
2. In `initWithPost:Script:`, you are creating a `NSURLConnection` object with a request object that is `nil`. This line:

   ```
   self->_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
   ```

   should be moved to the line after `[self.request setHTTPBody:postData];`.
3. In `initWithPost:Script:`, using `self->` is not necessary. You can access the ivars simply as `_postString`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. Can't thank you enough!